# Run terminal commands from within LibreOffice's Basic programming?

Tags: scripting, libreoffice

Is there a way to run system commands in LibreOffice Basic macros so that macros will be able to do things outside LibreOffice (e.g. changing keyboard layout)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. I once asked a [similar question](https://superuser.com/q/633381/163316) on SU.

The answer directed me to [the `Shell` function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Other_Functions_(Runtime_Library))

Basic usage (from the `Shell` function link):

> Shell(Pathname, Windowstyle, Param, bSync)
>
> #### Pathname
>
> the path of the program to be executed.
>
> #### Windowstyle
>
> the window in which the program is started.
>   The following values are possible:
>
> 0 - The program receives the focus and is started in a concealed window.
>   1 - The program receives the focus and is started in a normal-sized window.
>   2 - The program receives the focus and is started in a minimized window.
>   3 - The program receives the focus and is started in a maximized window.
>   4 - The program is started in a normal-sized window, without receiving the focus.
>   6 - The program is started in a minimized window, the focus remains in the current window.
>   10 - The program is started in full screen mode.
>
> #### Param
>
> command line parameters to be transferred to the program to be started.
>
> #### bSync
>
> wait for shell command to finish flag
>   true - wait for shell command to finish
>   false - don't wait for shell command to finish

Comment: `Shell("command")` works.

Comment: Is there a way to use this when I open a particular slide in an Impress presentation?

Comment: How about running system commands from formulas? Is Calc susceptible to [this exploit](http://georgemauer.net/2017/10/07/csv-injection.html)?