# libreOffice calc run bash script

Tags: linux, shell-script, libreoffice

i'm linux and i try to run a basic shell-script named script.sh with Shell command in libre office calc but i keep getting the error: BASIC runtime error. File not found.#

file path: 
`/home/username/script.sh`

my libre office calc code is:

```
sub test
shell("/home/username/script.sh",1,0,true)
end sub
```

i used this link as example for Shell command: [Run terminal commands from within LibreOffice's Basic programming?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140537/run-terminal-commands-from-within-libreoffices-basic-programming/140553#140553)

Comment: Welcome! Are you certain the path to the script and the name are correct?

Comment: thank you.  and yes i think. i'm still a beginner in linux but when when i type in a terminal:   cd /home/username                    my script is there

Comment: Please add all information to the question. Does the script work when you execute `/home/username/script.sh` in your terminal? If not, please copy&paste the command and the output.

Comment: sorry i forgot to precise it. The scrip run when i execute it. but i have to do it as root.  i don't have to enter the password tho because i modified the sudoers file in /etc/